# The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration error in php7.2.10

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I'm getting an error when logging in to phpMyAdmin `The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.` Few days before everything working fine. I have checked all extensions in php.ini and uncommented

`extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On`

and checked phpinfo();
[image]

And restart apache. But still getting the same error. I tried all possible ways unfortunately unable to resolve the error. Can anyone suggest me How to fix this issue ( using php7.2.10 apache2.4.35 )

Comment: If your php.ini file contains entries like `extension=php_mysql.dll` or `extension=php_mysqli.dll` it's very likely that you're editing the wrong file (from some 5.x versions you may have around).

Comment: The screen print above has the name of the php.ini file you need to edit, but also check what the phpinfo says about mysqli.

Comment: @NigelRen where i have to see about mysqli

Comment: If you just search for mysql on the page.

Comment: @NigelRen `Version mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $` showing this it is fine.

Comment: @NigelRen i want to try this cmd  `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` but i dont know in windows how to pass this command.

Comment: I hadn't realised the wampserver tag. If you are using a third-party bundle with graphic administration, shouldn't you be using such administration to do stuff like this? If you edit php.ini manually you possibly risk breaking the installation.

Comment: Can you show the section of phpinfo for `mysqli` please

Comment: @RiggsFolly Check above comment thanks for giving your time. Now I just reinstalled wamp its working fine now.

Comment: Then its best to delete the question, in case it attracts downvotes

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah but sometimes if we delete question they will block to ask any other questions.

Comment: Oh really, I didnt know that